# how to remove the "/digit" numbers from output

Tags: python

I need to remove the patch-set numbers from the output meaning remove the "/digit" from 1293927/2 1293929/3 ,i have shown the expected output below,the output should be as shown below but should be of type list.. how to split this?

```
   sql_get = """SELECT gerrit_id
                FROM gerrits.gerrit_submit_table
                where (SI='%s'
                and component='%s' and release_bit = '0' and picked_bit = '0')"""%(SI,component)

#print sql_get
rows = cursor.execute(sql_get)  
gerrits = cursor.fetchall() 
#print "gerrits"
#print gerrits -->prints (('1293927/2',), ('1293929/2',))


print' '.join(item[0] for item in gerrits).rstrip('\r\n') --> prints 1293927/2 1293929/2
```

OUTPUT:-

```
1293927/2 1293929/2
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
1293927 1293929
```

Comment: `print ' '.join(item[0][:-2] for item in gerrits).rstrip('\r\n')`

Comment: Is what's getting print the correct data from the database? If so, then that part is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re` module.

```
import re
print ' '.join(re.sub(r'/.*', '',item[0]) for item in gerrits).rstrip('\r\n')
```

**or**

Use `string.split` function.

```
print ' '.join(item[0].split('/')[0] for item in gerrits).rstrip('\r\n')
```

Update:

```
l = []
for item in gerrits:
    m = item[0].split('/')[0] 
    l.append(m)
print l
```

Comment: `print ' '.join(re.sub(r'/\d+$', '',item[0]) for item in gerrits).rstrip('\r\n')`

Comment: is there a way to send the output as a list instead of string?

Comment: output should still be 1293927 1293929 but it should be of type list

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider using a `split()`:

```
print ' '.join(item[0].split('/')[0] for item in gerrits)
```

This should negate the need for rsplit and handle any amount of digits after the slash.  Note that it outputs a `string`, but I assume that's what you're looking for given the `join()`.

*New requirement:*

Output as list:

```
print [item[0].split('/')[0] for item in gerrits)]
```

Comment: is there a way to send this as a list instead of string?

Comment: `print [item[0].split('/')[0] for item in gerrits]`

Comment: i mean the output should still be `1293927 1293929` but it should be of type list..

Comment: I wrote it already.  Check it: 
`type([item[0].split('/')[0] for item in gerrits])`
`<type 'list'>`

Comment: can you edit your answer ?the output should still be `1293927 1293929 `but it should be of type list,with above output will be `['1293927', '1293929']`